# Awarded extra 'fanatic' badges

Tags: bug, badges

I am just curious to know as to why I have been awarded three 'fanatic' badges, all at the same time? I am aware that I have earned one, but I am curious if the other two are the result of some sort of bug or if this is meant to happen.
Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Fanatic badge is supposed to be [earned once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75078/214632). Otherwise [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=622) would have earned 19 of them for the 19 disjoint 100 consecutive day periods he has visited the site (or 197 for the 197 different 100 consecutive day periods he has visited the site).

The fact that you earned [three in five minute intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=250221) is most certainly a bug. Multiple awarded Fanatic/Enthusiast badges [have occured before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46127). That case had to do with accounts being merged, which I cannot see in your account history.

Comment: Is there any way I could have the two extra badges removed? I don't feel I should have them if I haven't earned them (and if it isn't possible to earn them anyway).

Comment: @BenS. A CM or dev will have to do that. They'll probably also try to figure out exactly what happened here so that it doesn't happen again. With the [meta-tag:bug] tag, someone from SE _will_ see this question, but I can't say how long it will take to resolve it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm closing in on the 2k. :-)

Comment: Are moderators allowed to disclose other users consecutive days visited information? I am only curious if there is another way to see them as a common user.

Comment: @MakotoK. Probably not in general, but there's little harm in this particular case. Asaf's consecutive days streak has been a fairly [open secret](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9263) for a while. I'm pretty sure that searching through the SEDE would be able to verify most of this. (And Asaf doesn't seem to mind this publicity.)

Comment: I got this badge today and stumbled upon this page soon. Why hasn't OP's 3 Fanatic badges resolved yet?